# Parse ZonedDateTime.now() with DateTimeFormatter in Java

Tags: java, datetime-format, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime

I am trying to parse the current timestamp with specific format but every try I keep getting a `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`. My code:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(
    ZonedDateTime.now().toString(),
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")
            .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")) //I also tried ZoneId.systemDefault()
)
```

Result:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
Text '2018-02-27T11:01:18.776+01:00[Europe/Berlin]' could not be parsed at index 2
```

The question is why I can't parse it in the desired format and how to achieve it?

P.S. I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004123/java8-zoneddatetime-with-datetimeformatter-not-recognizing-the-format) post and tried setting the `ZoneId` but it didn't help.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Uhm... those specified in the formatter parameter.

Comment: Try `ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("...."))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse the result from `ZonedDateTime.toString()` back you don’t need an explicit formatter at all:

```
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(
            ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")).toString()));
```

This printed

> 2018-02-27T21:48:16.214832+08:00[Asia/Kuala_Lumpur]

The formatter from your question works nicely for formatting:

```
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")));
```

This printed:

> 27.02.2018 21:48:16.237

Did you confuse the word usage? **Parsing** means analyzing a string in order to make sense of it, in this case converting it to a date-time object like `ZonedDateTime`. The opposite conversion is called **formatting**, converting the date-time object into a string in a specific format, typically for human readability or data interchange.

Answer (score 1):

The DateTimeFormat

```
"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

does not match with

```
'2018-02-27T11:01:18.776+01:00[Europe/Berlin]'
```

produced by

```
ZonedDateTime.now().toString()
```

Comment: I know it doesn't. I thought formatter is used to format the non matching input to the desired output

Comment: But you try to parse the String in a different format.

Comment: ZonedDateTime.now().toString() produces a Date String in a default format which you try to parse afterwards with a different format.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for converting the `now()` result **String --> Date**, as the right formatter is already in the JDK:

```
String inputStr = ZonedDateTime.now().toString();
ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(inputStr, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME) 


System.out.println(parsed);
```

If you want to go the otheway around you convert the **Date --> String** via

```
 DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        String parsed = pattern.format(ZonedDateTime.now());
        System.out.println(parsed);
```

Comment: It works but I don't want the timezone and offset to be displayed. I want the format I specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the format function of the ZonedDateTime. For example:

```
String dateString = ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

You can as well look at:

- [How to parse/format dates with LocalDateTime? (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8/22463063#22463063)
- https://www.mscharhag.com/java/java-8-date-time-api