# Convert a string to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, datetime-format, zoneddatetime

I need to convert the string 2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000 to a ZonedDateTime. I tried the below but they didnt work:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z");
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000", formatter));

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss 00:00");
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000", formatter));

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss 0000");
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000", formatter));
```

I used the ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME as well but that didnt work. Any ideas?

Update:

I tried below :

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTime1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000",
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
    System.out.println(dateTime1.toZonedDateTime());
```

I get output as 2020-04-15T23:00Z but I need it as 2020-04-15T23:00:00Z with the seconds at the end which this is trimming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java8- ZonedDateTime with DateTimeFormatter not recognizing the format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004123/java8-zoneddatetime-with-datetimeformatter-not-recognizing-the-format)

Comment: @Dwhitz No it doesnt.

Comment: Your pattern has a space between seconds and the time zone, while the actual values doesn't have a space there. And if you want to print a `ZonedDateTime` in a specific pattern, you should use a formatter with that pattern to format it (eg `formatter.format(dateTime1)`. A `ZonedDateTime` itself has no pattern (it uses a default format when you call `toString()`)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Can you please look at my update in the question. I removed the space and it does work but it strips off the seconds from the end.

Comment: The second part of my comment addresses that. When you use `System.out.println(..)` it uses `toString()`, which always uses the same formatter to generate a string representation of the date, and in that formatter, seconds are optional. If you want to use a different format (eg one where seconds aren't optional), you need to explicitly use the formatter (eg `System.out.println(formatter.format(dateTime1))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .appendPattern("XX")
            .toFormatter();
    String str = "2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> 2020-04-15T23:00Z

Since your input string contains an offset, `+0000`, and no time zone, prefer to represent the date and time as an `OffsetDateTime`, not a `ZonedDateTime` (if you’ve got specific reasons for needing a `ZonedDateTime`, just use that class instead in the above code, it will work too).

I prefer to use the built-in formatters over writing my own format pattern string. Only for the offset I am using the format pattern `XX` (there are other patterns that will work too).

> I get output as 2020-04-15T23:00Z but I need it as
>   2020-04-15T23:00:00Z with the seconds at the end which this is
>   trimming.

You most probably don’t. The format is ISO 8601, and in ISO 8601 the seconds are optional when they are 0. The `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` has full precision (of nanoseconds, even). The omission (what you called trimming) only happens in the output produced by the `toString` method of the object. If you need the ISO 8601 format for some other API or other system, the variant without the seconds should work too.

If you do need a particular format, use a second `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting into a string in that needed format.

### What went wrong in your code?

Mark Rotteveel said it already: ISO 8601 allows no space between the time and the UTC offset. Or to put it the other way around, when in your format pattern string you put a space between `ss` and `Z`, parsing will require a space in the parsed string. Since there was no space, parsing failed.

### Links

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- Related question: [Cannot parse String in ISO 8601 format, lacking colon in offset, to Java 8 Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360852/cannot-parse-string-in-iso-8601-format-lacking-colon-in-offset-to-java-8-date)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert like following, it supports all of the following input formats

```
"2012-10-01T19:30:00+0200"
"2012-10-01T19:30:00+02" 
"2012-10-01T19:30:00+02:00"
"2012-10-01T19:30:00Z"
```

Code piece

```
        DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXX][XX][X]");


        OffsetDateTime osdt1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-04-15T23:00:01+0000", dtf1);
        OffsetDateTime osdt2 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-04-15T23:00:43+0900", dtf1);
        OffsetDateTime osdt3 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000", dtf1);
        OffsetDateTime osdt4 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-04-15T23:00:00+0900", dtf1);
        System.out.println("2020-04-15T23:00:01+0000 --> " + osdt1.toString());
        System.out.println("2020-04-15T23:00:43+0900 --> " + osdt2.toString());
        System.out.println("2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000 --> " + osdt3.toString());
        System.out.println("2020-04-15T23:00:00+0900 --> " + osdt4.toString());

        System.out.println("\n");

        DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        System.out.println("2020-04-15T23:00:01+0000 --> " + dtf2.format(osdt1));
        System.out.println("2020-04-15T23:00:43+0900 --> " + dtf2.format(osdt2));
        System.out.println("2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000 --> " + dtf2.format(osdt3));
        System.out.println("2020-04-15T23:00:00+0900 --> " + dtf2.format(osdt4));
```

output of above piece

```
2020-04-15T23:00:01+0000 --> 2020-04-15T23:00:01Z
2020-04-15T23:00:43+0900 --> 2020-04-15T23:00:43+09:00
2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000 --> 2020-04-15T23:00Z
2020-04-15T23:00:00+0900 --> 2020-04-15T23:00+09:00


2020-04-15T23:00:01+0000 --> 2020-04-15T23:00:01+0000
2020-04-15T23:00:43+0900 --> 2020-04-15T23:00:43+0900
2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000 --> 2020-04-15T23:00:00+0000
2020-04-15T23:00:00+0900 --> 2020-04-15T23:00:00+0900
```