# Parsing a ZonedDateTime String with timezone offset value

Tags: java, date, parsing, iso8601, zoneddatetime

I am trying to parse an ISO8601 time string of format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" using the below line for ZonedDateTime object:

```
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-02-19T14:32:12+0000", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```

However I am getting the below error when doing this:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-02-19T14:32:12+0000' could not be parsed at index 19
```

I cant imagine this is not allowed as the + symbol is a valid character for the parse. Can anyone assist on what is wrong here?

Comment: [My answer  here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66232081/5772882) might be helpful? Or this question; [Convert a string to ZonedDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61269697/convert-a-string-to-zoneddatetime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>That is because `ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` expects both an offset and a zone.</strike> See edit, it is not required in all cases. It is because the offset must contain a colon.

See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME).

Use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxx", Locale.ROOT)` instead. Alternatively, you could use the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```java
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
    .appendPattern("xx")
    .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
```

#### Edit

Only reading the *summary fragment* of the Javadoc is apparently not enough. The zone id is not strictly required by the `ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`, as mentioned in the comments. The second bullet point there mentions it: *"If the zone ID is not available or is a ZoneOffset then the format is complete"*.

Comment: Thank you, this approach works and I opted to use the older format syntax as the offset needs to have the 4 digits present rather than two.

DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ROOT)

Comment: `ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` lives happily without the zone ID. The documentation that you link to says that *If the zone ID is not available … then the format is complete* after the zone offset. The real problem was the lack of colon in the offset. You are correct that `xx` in the format pattern string solves it (no matter if using a builder or not).